# Heroku won't load my venv, and won't let me open my app

Tags: django, heroku, python-venv

which is simply "It worked" server screen. I'm tryin gto do the GettingStartedWithDjango tutorial. Yes, I am an idiot.

> (blog-venv)vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/projects/micrblog$ git push
>   heroku master Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP
>   address '50.19.85.156' to the list of known hosts. Counting objects:
>   11, done. Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done. Writing objects: 100%
>   (11/11), 3.60 KiB, done. Total 11 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> -----> Python app detected
>   -----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.4.
>   -----> Preparing Python runtime (python-2.7.4)
>   -----> Installing Distribute (0.6.36)
>   -----> Installing Pip (1.3.1)
>   -----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.3.1)
>          Downloading/unpacking Django==1.4.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
>            Running setup.py egg_info for package Django
>
> ```
>    Downloading/unpacking argparse==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
>      Running setup.py egg_info for package argparse
>
>        no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
>        no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
>        no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
>        no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
>        no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
>    Installing collected packages: Django, argparse
>      Running setup.py install for Django
>        changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/django-admin.py from 600 to 755
>
>        changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/django-admin.py to 755
>      Running setup.py install for argparse
>
>        no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
>        no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
>        no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
>        no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
>        no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
>    Successfully installed Django argparse
>    Cleaning up...
> ```
>
> -----> Collecting static files
>          0 static files copied.
>
> -----> Discovering process types
>          Procfile declares types -> web
>
> -----> Compiled slug size: 29.2MB
>   -----> Launching... done, v6
>          http://fathomless-mountain-2524.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
>
> To git@heroku.com:fathomless-mountain-2524.git  * [new branch]
>   master -> master
>   (blog-venv)vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/projects/micrblog$ heroku run
>   /bin/bash Running `/bin/bash` attached to terminal... up, run.3161 ~ $
>   pip freeze Django==1.4.3 argparse==1.2.1 distribute==0.6.36
>   wsgiref==0.1.2"

Comment: What's the question in here? If I go to the [link](http://fathomless-mountain-2524.herokuapp.com) that is listed there it says Django has been installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the the [Getting Started with Django on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) tutorial it states:

> Here, one dyno is running.
>
> We can now visit the app in our browser with heroku open.
>
> `$ heroku open`
>
> `Opening simple-spring-9999.herokuapp.com... done`
>
> You should see the satisfying “It worked!” Django welcome page.

I am seeing this from [your link](http://fathomless-mountain-2524.herokuapp.com/) so everything is working okay.

Comment: Thanks, just now getting back on this horse and ran into the same "problem" again. I was then and just was now terribly confused because where his version of heroku had open app mine had "run production check" i.e. they changed their interface, if I hit that launch box by the app title I my app works and those fails in the loading were just a red herring.  BUT without your comment I would have continued to panic and not noticed the launch box dealio!